# integrate a view into another view in iphone

Tags: iphone, subview

Good Day!

i want to add a subview in another view in iphone. and i want that child view to be of size which i want like if i want to change its height/width i can. Can somebody please suggest me something or help me out in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]  ;
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: but i want to integrate google adsense into this new uiview. how can i do that,